# Submit form on any input changes with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form that use selects and checkboxes.

For checkbox I use this method:

http://jsfiddle.net/nvanh/eomesgya/

The problem comes when I try to submit form on any change with:

```
    $('#filter_form').on('change', function () {
        console.log('submit');
    });
```

If I change the select option the event fire but when I check a checkbox is not.

Here is the complete code:

http://jsfiddle.net/eomesgya/2/

Comment: you dont really want to submit the form until the user finishes selecting their check boxes though.  It would be bad to submit the form after each time a check box was clicked.  It doesnt make sense from an HCI point of view to submit after each check

Comment: Are you sure you shouldn't be using Radio Buttons here?

Comment: I need to do this to show real time results on a real estate website. If you check a city, show results, if you check another show results for both values.

Comment: Then I don't think you want to submit the form on the clicking of the checkbox, I think you want to initiate an AJAX call.

Comment: Yes but I wanted to do the submit to get all the post params easy in ajax based on form id. How do you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should manually trigger change event if u manually change checked state:

```
$('.dropdown-menu a').on('click', function (event) {
    ....
    setTimeout(function () {
        $inp.prop('checked', true);
        $inp.trigger('change'); // add this line
    }, 0);
    ....
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to bind it to each input element in the form, not just the form itself. Maybe try something like

```
$('#filter_form input').each(function() { 
   $(this).on('change', function () {
        console.log('submit');
        // Do submission stuff, submit form
    });
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/submit/ As well if you need.

Comment: Have you tested it in his fiddle?

Comment: Fiddle is busted for me it seems.

Answer (score 0):

You should bind Change Event to every input of your form, and this event should trigger the Submit event from your form.

```
$("#post-editor :input").each(function(){

    // Every input of your form on $(this) scope

    $(this).on('change', function () {

        $("#post-editor").submit();
    });
})
```